# Notify react components about value change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose that I have a component class which is responsible to change any **number** entered into textbox to **text**:

```
class NumbersToText extends Component {

  onChange(event) {
    const { target } = event;
    const { value } = target;

    if (hasNumbers(value)) {
      target.value = numbersToText(value);
      // HERE I NEED TO NOTIFY ABOUT CHANGES
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <span onChange={this.onChange}>
        {this.props.children}
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

Now the usage would look something like this:

```
<NumbersToText>
  <input onChange={this.saveValue}
</NumbersToText>
```

Let's say that all works, and the value gets changed to text.

Now **the problem** is that after I change numbers to text and assign that value to input `onChange` handlers are not executed again, thus `saveValue` is not called with updated value.

How should this problem be approached in order to trigger `onChange` handlers with new value?

Comment: Would you write down the whole related piece of code; like `saveValue` method? Also, you're just missing the closing input tag here not in your actual code I guess!

Comment: and what is `count` you're waiting for in props?

Comment: @BasimHennawi - yeah, this is only "pseudo code" to illustrate the problem, so the tags are missing only here. As for `count` - I removed it, that is a leftover from original code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you mean by `numbers to text` so I'll just assume you want to modify the value before calling the onChange function in the input, and also reflect that value in the input.

First of all, what you're doing will never work on React, React reflects internal `virtual` objects into the DOM, meaning you shloud not modify the DOM directly and instead you should modify this internal representantion (via setState, props) to reflect this change into the DOM.

There's also two types of inputs on React, controlled and uncontrolled. I will assume you want to use this on uncontrolled inputs.

The only possible solution I can see, is to *transform* the input using the `React.cloneElement` function adding a aditional step before calling the input's `onChange` callback.

Here's a possible implementation that will make the input uppercase.

```
class UpperCase extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);            
    }

    onChange(e, input, next) {
      let value = input.value || '';
      value = value.toUpperCase();
      input.value = value;
      next(value);
    }

    render() {
      let childs = React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => {
        let input = null; //Will take advantage of javascript's closures
        let onChangeChild = child.props.onChange.bind(child);
        return React.cloneElement(child, { 
            ref: ref => input = ref,
            onChange: e => {
              this.onChange(e, input, onChangeChild)
            }
        });
      });
      return (
        <span>
            {childs}
        </span>
      );
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
<UpperCase>
  <input onChange={(val) => console.log(val)}></input>  
  <textarea onChange={(val) => console.log(val)}></textarea>  
</UpperCase>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @tiagohngl I came up with a similar, but maybe a little less cluttered (without cloning elements) way:

```
class NumbersToText extends Component {

  onChange(event) {
    const { target } = event;
    const { value } = target;

    if (hasNumbers(value)) {
      target.value = numbersToText(value);

      this.childrenOnChange(event);
    }
  }

  childrenOnChange(event) {
    const { children } = this.props;

    React.Children.forEach(children, child => {
      if (child.props.onChange) {
        child.props.onChange(event);
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <span onChange={this.onChange}>
        {this.props.children}
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export default class NumbersToText extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({ anyData: [] });
}

onChange(event) {
    this.setState({anyData: event.target.value},
    ()=>{console.log("AnyData: "+this.state.anyData)});
    // callback to console.log after setState is done
}

render() {
    return (
        <input type="text"
            value={this.state.anyData}
            onChange={this.onChange} />
        );
    }
}
```

As you mention that,
onChange is not called after changed value.

There are multiple possibilities.

1. onChange is not binded.
2. There are no state change in render method, so it will not re-render
3. make use of console.log() to trace the problem

I slightly ammend the code for illustration.

Hope it helps.

[How react handle State Change (answer I posted before)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40123298/how-does-react-createclass-work/40124262#40124262)